# USe of transloadit plugin without file browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, transloadit

I tried use of [transloadit plugin](https://transloadit.com/) for change natural size of image and show it to a user , but it doesn't work for me. how can done it?

**SEE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bx1en700/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#my_img').transloadit({
    wait: true,
    triggerUploadOnFileSelection: true,

    params: {
      auth: { key: "YOUR-AUTH-KEY" }, 
      steps: {
        cropped_thumb: {
          use: ":original",
          robot: "/image/resize",
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          resize_strategy: "crop"
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jsfiddle.net/bx1en700/assets.transloadit.com/js/jquery.transloadit2-v2-latest.js"></script>

<img id="my_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/SHo6Fub.jpg">
```

Comment: Your demo does not work because the `query.transloadit2-v2-latest.js` script file is not loading

Comment: Do you get an error when you try this outside of jsfiddle (not sure if that's gonna work)?. Also the url should be http://assets.transloadit.com/js/jquery.transloadit2-v2-latest.js